# Apply the position of each column in a row as a negative margin

Tags: javascript, jquery, position

I need to first get the left position of each column in each row, and then apply that as a negative margin to a div within the column. I have it working with some hardcoded javascript, but I know there's a more elegant solution.

The HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column column_1"><!-- Content --></div>
  <div class="column column_2"><!-- Content --></div>
  <div class="column column_3"><!-- Content --></div>
  <div class="column column_4"><!-- Content --></div>
</div>
```

My ugly JS:

```
var adjustMargin1 = jQuery(".column_1").position().left;
var adjustMargin2 = jQuery(".column_2").position().left;

ETC...

jQuery(".column_1 .adjusted-div").css("margin-left", -adjustMargin1);
jQuery(".column_2 .adjusted-div").css("margin-left", -adjustMargin2);
```

Comment: May I ask if the left position is different in each column? Im just trying to picture what this might look like to come up with the optimal solution

Comment: It is different for each, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
$('.column').each(function(s, el) {
  $(el).find('.adjusted-div').eq(0).css('margin-left',-($(el).position().left));
});
```

Looping over each .column element, finding the adjusted-div element within, then applying the position left from the parent as a margin-left to the child.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks! What exactly is the "s" doing in the function definition, and why is eq(0) necessary?

Comment: The s is just a numerical index, you don't actually need it there (or the el, you could just use $(this) instead), it's just force of habit that I always add it. The eq(0) might not be necessary, it depends on your HTML structure (e.g. whether you have multiple divs that match the class and whether you want the class to apply to them all) - feel free to remove it if these restrictions don't apply in your case :)

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for clarifying :)